# Simple Voltage Calculation

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, voltage-measurement

Could you please help me about calculating the voltage on the 100 ohm resistor. I know the result is 0.708 V but how could I calculate it, is there an easy way for that?.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

According to [Kirchhoff's Current Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29), at a point, the sum of incoming or sum of outgoing currents must be zero (unless there is a charge accumulating on that point, and this is not our case).

We take the red point in the bottom as our reference point; we will assume that its potential is zero volts. This is just OK since we are only concerned with the potential differences rather than the actual potentials; and also your question is asking the voltage across a resistor, not potentials at its terminals.
Next, we define another node (X - the top red point), and call its potential V<sub>x</sub>. Our aim will be forming an equation with this unknown V<sub>x</sub> variable, and then solve for it.

So, we write the sum of currents at the X point:

$$ I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 0 \dots (1) \\
I_1 = \frac{V_x - 5V}{150 \Omega} \dots (2) \\
I_2 = \frac{V_x}{100 \Omega} \dots (3) \\
I_3 = \frac{V_x - 0.45V}{12 \Omega} \dots (4) $$

Substitute (2), (3) and (4) into (1):

$$
\frac{V_x - 5V}{150 \Omega} + \frac{V_x}{100 \Omega} + \frac{V_x - 0.45V}{12 \Omega} = 0 \dots (5)$$

Rearrange the terms in (5):

$$
30V_x - 21.25V = 0 \\
V_x = 0.7083333...V $$

You were right. Since V<sub>x</sub> corresponds to the voltage on the 100\$ \Omega \$ resistor, it indeed equals to 0.708V.

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest done, IMO, with nodal analysis:

Call the node on the top-right V (above the 0.45V source). You have 3 branches to consider, the branch on the left with the 5V and 150ohm resistor, the branch with the 0.45V and 12ohm resistor, and the branch with the 100ohm resistor. Consider the bottom node to be GND.

Your nodal equation is:

\$\frac{V-5}{150} + \frac{V-0.45}{12} + \frac{V}{100} = 0\$

Solve for V, you get \$V = \frac{17}{24} = 0.7083V.\$

That's all you need to do to find that voltage, but with that you can solve for all currents, all node voltages, and all powers.

In case you're not familiar with nodal analysis:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis